# How to Scale Down HDMI Output in Android

Tags: java, android, scale

I am an Android developer and I am working for a set top box project. I want to be able to change the width and height of the display. Because, on the some of the televisions which I use with our box and HDMI cable, the display is bigger than the panel of TV. It doesn't look good. I want to develop an application to allow users changing the size of display. How can I do this? I am waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on AV so take what I say lightly.

It sounds like your TV is overscanning. If your android is outputting 720p or 1080p the TV shouldnt be doing that. Check some settings in the TV to make sure it isn't trying to adjust the size of the picture automatically.

It could also be that the Android is refusing to output anything but 1080p and your TV can't handle it and thus attempts to display what it kind. I've found most TVs just refuse to work with resolutions they can't handle but yours might be different.

Comment: My android outputs 1080 p and this happens on some TVs not at all. The main question is to change size(reduce generally) programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you could have a piece of sw to fix this.
Really need a fix for this too.
My X5A is also overscaled. Cannot enjoy my HDMI output this way.